# If sets $A, B$ are countable infinite then also $A \cup B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**This is my first „own“ proof I created. Is it ok? Are there things fishy? I‘d appreciate if someone could go thru my proof step by step and point out mistakes if there are any. $\Bbb N^{2n}$ means the even natural numbers and $\Bbb N^{2n+1}$ means the odd natural numbers.**

Theorem: If sets $A, B$ are countable infinite then also $A \cup B$.

Proof: We assume that sets $A,B$ are countable infinite, i.e. $|A| = |\Bbb N| = |B|$, i.e. $f: A \to \Bbb N$ and $g: B \to \Bbb N$ are bijective.

We also know that $|\Bbb N^{2n}| = |\Bbb N| = |\Bbb N^{2n+1}|$.

It follows $|A| = |\Bbb N^{2n}|$ and $ |B| = |\Bbb N^{2n+1}|$, i.e. $f‘: A \to \Bbb N^{2n}$ and $g‘: B \to \Bbb N^{2n+1}$ are bijective.

Now we assume a function $h: A \cup B \to \Bbb N$ thru the rule: if $x \in A$ then $f‘(x)$, if $x \in B-A$ then $g‘(x)$.

The function $h$ is bijective. First it is injective because every preimage $x \in A \cup B$ has exactly one image due to the distribution of $f‘(x)$ and $g‘(x)$. It is also surjective because every image in $\Bbb N$ has exactly one preimage due to $f‘$, $g‘$.

But since $h$ is bijective it follows by definition $|A \cup B| = |\Bbb N|$ and that‘s by definition a case of countable infinity for $A \cup B$.

Comment: I don't think this is right. Consider the sets $A = \{1,2\}$, $B = \{ 3 \}$ and the injections $f: A \to \mathbb{N}$, $g: B \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2$, $g(3) = 2$. Then $h$ defined as you did wouldn't be an injection because $h(2) = f(2) = g(3) = h(3)$. You can fix it by making $h$ a function into $\mathbb{N}^2$, that has the same cardinality than $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: It looks like you have a good idea, but use the wrong terminology: It appears as if you're confused about the meaning of $\Bbb N^n$. Usually $\Bbb N^n$ means sequences of elements of $\Bbb N$ of length $n$, or equivalently functions from $n$ to $\Bbb N$, while you seem to want to use it as two disjoint *copies* of $\Bbb N$. Instead, I'd write this as $\{0\}\times\Bbb N$ and $\{1\}\times\Bbb N$, having elements $(0,n)$ and $(1,n)$ respectively. Then, send $x\in A$ to $(0,f(x))$ and $x\in B-A$ to $(1,g(x))$.

Comment: @Zanzag: If Don Thousand is right in his guess about the meaning of $\mathbb N^{2n}$ and $\mathbb N^{2n+1}$, it is implied that $f'$ must have even values and $g'$ must have odd values, which is not true about your counterexample.

Comment: it is better to count in $A\times B$

Comment: @Troposphere Yes, if that was what meant by the OP then I would say the proof is alright, although It can me made much clearer.

Comment: A more substantial problem with the construction here is that if $A$ and $B$ overlap, for example $x\in A\cap B$, then $g'(x)$ will be missing from the range of $h$ -- so $h$ is not surjective onto $\mathbb N$ as you claim.

Comment: I do not see the problem with my proof. 1) Yes, $\Bbb N^{2n}$ means the even natural numbers and the other means the odd numbers. 2) My construction has no problem with an overlap since I differ between A and B\A which results in $A \cup B$ without an overlap. Instead of an alternative proof I‘d be interested in someone going thru my proof steps and pointing out mistakes or ambiguities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you request in the comments for someone to specifically critique your proof, I'll do that here.

---

First, as mentioned, the notation $\Bbb N^{2n}$ for the even integer is highly unusual, and will certainly confuse your readers. As with numbers, one expects $\Bbb N^2$ to mean $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$, and $\Bbb N^3$ to mean $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N\times\Bbb N$, and thus $\Bbb N^{2n}$ is usually seen as the cartesian product of $2n$ many copies of $\Bbb N$ (or alternatively as the set of functions from $2n=\{0,1,2,\dots,2n-1\}$ to $\Bbb N$).

To describe subsets unambiguously, one usually uses set builder notation, such as $\{2n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$, which would be the set of even natural numbers. Some standard symbols for the even & odd numbers are $\Bbb E$ & $\Bbb O$, or $E$ & $O$ or $2\Bbb N$ & $2\Bbb N+1$.

---

> Proof: We assume that sets $A,B$ are countable infinite, i.e. $|A| = |\Bbb N| = |B|$, i.e. $f: A \to \Bbb N$ and $g: B \to \Bbb N$ are bijective.

You mention $f$ and $g$, but they aren't used in the proof after this. I'd not state that $f$ and $g$ are bijective, since before this sentence these functions were still undefined. Instead, I'd say *"hence, there exist bijective functions $f:A\to\Bbb N$ and $g:B\to \Bbb N$."*

> We also know that $|\Bbb N^{2n}| = |\Bbb N| = |\Bbb N^{2n+1}|$.
>
> It follows $|A| = |\Bbb N^{2n}|$ and $ |B| = |\Bbb N^{2n+1}|$, i.e. $f‘: A \to \Bbb N^{2n}$ and $g‘: B \to \Bbb N^{2n+1}$ are bijective.

Same as before, you *define* $f`$ and $g`$. As far as symbols are concerned, you could consider using an apostrophe ' instead of a backtick `.

> Now we assume a function $h: A \cup B \to \Bbb N$ thru the rule: if $x \in A$ then $f‘(x)$, if $x \in B-A$ then $g‘(x)$.

We don't assume $h$, we define it. Also, "then $f`(x)$" doesn't mean anything, you should state "then $h(x)=f`(x)$" instead.

> The function $h$ is bijective. First it is injective because every preimage $x \in A \cup B$ has exactly one image due to the distribution of $f‘(x)$ and $g‘(x)$. It is also surjective because every image in $\Bbb N$
> has exactly one preimage due to $f‘$, $g‘$.
>
> But since $h$ is bijective it follows by definition $|A \cup B| = |\Bbb N|$ and that‘s by definition a case of countable infinity for $A \cup B$.

This is arguably the crux of the proof, but unfortunately also where the proof is most wrong. "Due to" is not exactly precise enough, and indeed it is even incorrect in the argument of surjectivity.

The reason that no two $x,x'\in A\cup B$ map to the same element $h(x)=h(x')$ is because of three facts:

- $h\restriction A=f`$ is a bijection, and thus injective,
- $h\restriction (B-A)=g`\restriction (B-A)\subseteq g`$, and $g`$ is injective since $g`$ is a bijection,
- the range of $f`$ (the even numbers) and of $g`$ (the odd numbers) are disjoint.

This final point is crucially why the composite function $h$ is injective.

As far as surjectivity of $h$ is concerned, consider the following $A$, $B$, $f`$ and $g`$:

- $A=\{n\in\Bbb N\mid n\geq 1\}=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots\}$,
- $B=\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,3,4,\dots\}$,
- $f`:n\mapsto 2n-2$
- $g`:n\mapsto 2n+1$

Now the range of $h$ includes the range of $f`$ and thus includes all even numbers, but it does not include all odd numbers, since only $g`(0)=1$ is in the range of $h$. This is because $B-A=\{0\}$ contains only one element. So $h$ is not surjective. In fact, the way you defined $h$, we will only get surjectivity if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint sets.

However, this is actually not a problem: you don't have to give an explicit bijection between $A\cup B$ and $\Bbb N$. Instead, since $h$ is injective, you've already proved that $|A\cup B|\leq |\Bbb N|$, so it is enough to now find an injective function $\Bbb N\to A\cup B$. But this is easy, since $f:A\to \Bbb N$ is bijective, thus $f^{-1}:\Bbb N\to A$ fits our purpose.

Since $|A\cup B|\leq |\Bbb N|$ and $|\Bbb N|\leq |A\cup B|$, we have $|A\cup B|=|\Bbb N|$ by the [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) (note that this theorem is not as trivial as it looks symbolically).

---

If you don't want to use the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem, I suggest to split your $A\cup B$ into three sets: $X_1=A-B$, $X_2=B-A$ and $X_3=A\cap B$. You can then make a case distinction for which of the $X_i$ is finite and which of the $X_i$ is infinite. They can't all be finite by the pigeonhole principle. This way you can write down an explicit bijection as well, but it's a bit more work.

Comment: Huge help, thx. But then I go with the much simpler proof in my book: Let some $f: A \to \Bbb N $, $g: B \to \Bbb N$ be injective. We define $h: A \cup B \to \Bbb Z$ as: $f(x)$ for $x \in A$, $-(g(x)+1)$ for $x \in B-A$. Now, h is injective, i.e. $|A \cup B| \le |\Bbb Z| = |\Bbb N|$ which makes $A \cup B$ countably infinite due to the theorem that if $|A| \le |\Bbb N|$ then A is countably infinite.

Comment: @Pippen No, that's not enough and that's not a theorem. $|A|\leq |\Bbb N|$ implies that $|A|$ is *countable*, but clearly it does not necessarily have to be *infinite* (e.g. $0=|\varnothing|\leq |\Bbb N|$ as well). So, you'd still need to prove that $A\cup B$ is infinite.

Comment: In my book that is assumed. So the whole proof begins with the theorem: If A, B are countably infinite then A $\cup$ B is also countably infinite. Then it follows with what I have written above. I mean if A $ \cup$ B is not infinite then it is just finite and trivially countable. As I understand it therefore "countable" in set theory always means "countable infinite" because otherwise it's not interesting.

Comment: @Pippen Which book is this? "countable" means "either finite or countably infinite" in most sources that I know of. It depends on what the definition of "infinite" is in your book on how one proves that $A\cup B$ is infinite. Also, "it is assumed that $A\cup B$ is infinite" seems unlikely, since it's part of what you're trying to prove. You can't prove assumptions (only disprove them by arriving at a contradiction).

Comment: My book proves the theorem: if A, B are countably infinite sets then so its union is countably infinite. The point of interest is not if A $\cup$ B is infinite - that's trivial - but if it's countably infinite. Here's the link, but it's a german book: https://www.aleph1.info/?call=Puc&permalink=mengenlehre1_1_7_Z1, the theorem is marked blue, the proof marked red.

Comment: It seems you're reading the theorem incorrectly: https://www.aleph1.info/?call=Puc&permalink=mengenlehre1_1_7_Z1 Here it is proved that if $A,B$ are **countable**, then their union is **countable**. It does not mention infinity at all. Indeed, if $A,B$ are infinite, also $A\cup B$ is infinite, by the second Satz here: https://www.aleph1.info/?call=Puc&permalink=mengenlehre1_1_6_Z4 (and the fact that $A\subseteq A\cup B$). Combining these two gives that the union of two countably infinite sets is countably infinite, but you need both theorems.

Comment: One section earlier the author makes it clear that "countable" means "countable infinite" because he defines a set to be countable if there's a bijection to IN. So I read the proof as if infinity is presupposed to A, B and A $\cup$ B while it's only about if the infinity is countable or not. Otherwise the proof would get unnecessarily complicated like you point out correctly.

Comment: @Pippen Once again incorrect. Countable (abzählbar) means "countably infinite" **or** "finite". See the definition: https://www.aleph1.info/?call=Puc&permalink=mengenlehre1_1_7 ; a set is countable if (i) there is a bijection between some natural number and the set (i.e. the set is finite), or (ii) there is a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and the set. The proof does not get *unnecessarily* complicated: it's simply not as simple as you think it is.

Comment: I think if A, B are finite then trivially A $\cup$ B is also finite and any finite set is trivially countable in the sense of (i). Therefore I think the author silently just proved that if A,B is countable-infinite then so the union because that‘s not trivial. Another question for my understanding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set#Some_technical_details. There u find our proof but wrong, right?

Comment: @Pippen I'm not going to repeat myself. Please learn the difference between "countable" and "countably infinite". The author proves exactly what he states he proves.

Comment: Yes, his proof works for both cases of „countable“. What do you think about the proof at wikipedia? Doesn‘t it have the same flaw you pointed out here?